# How to configure dotNetOpenId in an session less load balancing environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, load-balancing, dotnetopenauth

You've probably solved this before.

I need to be able to use open id in an environment that does not have session stickiness. The servers do preserve the headers.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and dotNetOpenId version 3.2.0.9177. Although the authentication on the 3rd party web site goes without a hitch when returning the response I get an error and authentication fails.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Stateful**

The most optimized method is to write a custom persistence store that implements `IRelyingPartyApplicationStore` for the "secrets" that OpenID RPs require, and pass your instance to the `OpenIdRelyingParty(IRelyingPartyApplicationStore)` constructor, or register it in your [web.config file](http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/wiki/CodeSnippets/Configuration).

**Stateless**

A much easier solution that will suffice for most scenarios is to use stateless mode instead, so that no state needs to be shared across your web farm's servers.

You can activate stateless mode by instantiating `OpenIdRelyingParty` passing `null` in as your application store instance.  Calling the default constructor will cause DNOA to use its in-memory store, which breaks on server farms, so the default constructor is insufficient.

Or if you're using the ASP.NET controls, just set `Stateless = true` on the control.

Comment: Thanks. The stateless part seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how we're enabling stateless mode:

```
var uri = new Uri(Request.Url, Request.RawUrl);
var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty(null, uri, 
             Request.HttpMethod == "GET" ? Request.QueryString : Request.Form);
```

Seems to work so far, though per Andrew there's a small performance hit. Not sure that matters since login is a fairly rare activity.

Comment: This three-parameter constructor is appropriate for DotNetOpenId 2.x, whereas the one parameter constructor for stateless mode is suitable for DotNetOpenAuth 3.x.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Coding Horror/One-of-the-creators-of-stackoverflow. I'll try it monday morning.

Answer (score 1):

Using DotNetOpenID, you should be able to persist the state you need during authentication to the client via a cookie.

**Edit:** I don't have any example code for this because I've never had to use DotNetOpenID in a session-less environment, but I would check out this link, it may provide the information you need: http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/wiki/WebFarmHowto

Comment: I've used something similar for holding something in TempData, but any code examples for the DotNetOpenID ? I'm not familiar with it yet. Thanks

Comment: I don't have any code examples on hand, but check out the link I've provided.