# Why can't I log in with "claimid.com" as an OpenID?

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I need to implement a relying party for Open ID in a load balanced environment.

Following the suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379156) I have tried passing null to the OpenIdRelyingParty constructor.
The results are somehow not consistent.

If I use www.myopenid.com  as a provider it works.

If I use  www.claimid.com as a provider I get the following exception: ***ProtocolException*** - No OpenID endpoint found. This exception is thrown on the *CreateRequest* method call even in a non balanced environment (my local workstation).

Any idea what can I do to make it work for both providers ?

#### Update:

I have tried the following and unfortunately it doesn't work.

1. Updated *OpenIdRelyingParty* constructor in *DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.UserController* to use null as *IRelyingPartyApplicationStore*
2. Run the sample
3. Pass claimid.com/aarnott to the OpenId input
4. *ProtocolException*: No OpenID endpoint found.

The same sample works if I use the default parameterless constructor for *OpenIdRelyingParty*.
I ran the sample on my local machine.

Comment: I renamed your question title to better reflect the underlying question you were asking.  The load balanced environment actually had nothing to do with the problem.  This way, you and others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 2):

`www.claimid.com` is *not* an OpenID 2.0 Provider.  It only supports OpenID 1.1.  Therefore, typing `www.claimid.com` into an OpenID relying party will not work (OpenID 1.1 does not include identifier_select functionality, which is what you're trying to do).  You have to type in the individual's OpenID.  Try typing in `claimid.com/aarnott` and it will work just fine.

`myopenid.com` on the other hand *is* an OpenID 2.0 Provider, which is why you see that one working for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this whole ClaimID thing is broken anyway. I tried several times to register there, but a) there is no link to register anywhere and b) even trying to sign in with an existing OpenID won't work (after pressing "Continue" in myOpenID I just get forwarded to the log-in page of ClaimID again => endless loop)..

Also the last entry of the ClaimID blog (blog.claimid.com) is from Feb 09 and talks about a paid version etc., so I wouldn't hold my breath on ClaimID getting anywhere in the future