# Is the DotNetOpenAuth in-memory store sufficient for web farms with a load balancer that has sticky sessions?

Tags: .net, openid, load-balancing, dotnetopenauth, web-farm

I am implementing DoNetOpenAuth as an Relying Party in an web farm environment. Is the default in-memory store sufficient for environments with sticky sessions? I have read a few post alluding that it does work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379156/how-to-configure-dotnetopenid-in-an-session-less-load-balancing-environment) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid/browse_thread/thread/b352056bd1f8be2a), but I don't have enough knowledge of load balancing and OpenID to know for sure.

I understand it may not be ideal and that I should either run in "dumb" mode or implement my own store.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sticky sessions are *not* enough to permit the use of the in-memory store, because the store has data that must be available to multiple client parties (nonces, most particularly, in order to mitigate replay attacks).